# Are using-declaration collisions ODR violations?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, one-definition-rule

I found a pair of headers in Boost that include colliding names: https://github.com/boostorg/range/issues/126
One header in boost puts things in `namespace boost::sort`, another does `namespace boost { ... using ranges::sort; }`. If you just include both, the compiler doesn't complain, but if you then use `boost::sort(...)` (i.e., `boost::range::sort`), it is confused which `boost::sort` you mean: https://godbolt.org/z/f9qzcKM77. Interestingly, you can still use `boost::sort::pdqsort`: https://godbolt.org/z/3n11oM63v

My question: If in one compilation unit I `#include <boost/range/algorithm/sort.hpp>` and call `boost::sort(x)` and in another I `#include <boost/sort/pdqsort/pdqsort.hpp>` and call `boost::sort::pdqsort(std::begin(x), std::end(x))` and link it all together, is that an ODR violation? That is, does a `using` declaration interact with ODR or is `using` just a convenience at compile time?

For what it's worth, the calls are `call _ZN5boost5range4sortIA2_iEERT_S4_` and `call _ZN5boost4sort7pdqsortIPiEEvT_S3_` respectively (as I'd expect) so I'd think that these are totally separate definitions from a practical standpoint, but what about from a language-lawyer standpoint?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that aliases are just present at compile time they don't create new definitions and therefore don't cause ODR violations

Comment: `using` directive doesn't create new definitions, and so doesn't directly affect ODR. It merely guides name lookup; the lookup could find a declaration it wouldn't have found otherwise, or become ambiguous where it wouldn't be otherwise. Now, if you have, say, a class definition in a header, that refers to a certain name, and you include that header in two translation units where that name is resolved differently due to a `using` directive (or for any other reason) - that is in fact an ODR violation. So `using` directive can indirectly interact with ODR this way.